# Sequelize: is it possible to get a value of VIRTUAL field in a Raw Query?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

For example, I have a model

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: DataTypes.TEXT,
  lastName: DataTypes.TEXT,
  presentation: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
      return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    },
    set(value) {
      throw new Error('Do not try to set the `fullName` value!');
    }
  }
});
```

next I want to make a request like

```
let queryText =
      '\
      SELECT \
        user.firstName AS firstName, \
        user.lastName AS lastName \
      FROM \
        user as user'

const items = await sequelize.query(queryText, { type: QueryTypes.SELECT })
```

is it possible to include field "presentation" in such kind of query?

this is a very simplified example, in real case I have a much more complicated query with a lot of joins of tables, every of that table has own VIRTUAL field

I've tried to google, tried to ask chatGPT, tried to find such cases in existing projects, read carefully Sequelize documentation

Answer (score 0):

`VIRTUAL` fields are declared in model definitions and thus are used in queries using model's methods like `findAll` while raw SQL queries are used to execute the exact SQL query you indicated and to get the exact SQL result from it.

You can use pieces of raw SQL in model queries if you can in order to keep using `VIRTUAL` fields in models' queries.

There are `instance` and `model` options of the `query` method that you can use to transform raw SQL query results into model instances though I'm not sure if it suits your goal.